# How to read the generated source (html with DOM changes) of a webpage within javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I want to read a webpage programmatically (with javascript-angular) and search some elements inside. What i have until now is:

```
$http.get('http://.....').success(function(data) {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
    var result = doc.evaluate('//div[@class = \'xx\']/a', doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
    $scope.all = result.stringValue;
});
```

so in the example i can read the value of any html element.

**Very unluckily**, the page i want to read uses some Javascript and the source code (html) is just a part of its entire html source (including DOM changes), which the browser at the end shows. So the html which is returned  from the http get, does not necessarily contain the elements i need.

Is there a way of getting the entire html after the javascript run?

**Edit:** Yes the page is from another domain + The provided API does not give me the info i need.

Comment: you would need to run a headless browser on your server with a delay set to allow `asynchronous` code to create the elements, then get the html from your server

Comment: that is also what i actually thought but i was not sure if there is an easier way.. If you can paste a simple example as an answer i would be glad.

Comment: if you are on the same origin, put the page in an iframe.

Comment: there is no simpler way to get only partials if page is from another domain unless there is an exposed API you can use

Comment: Would `.load()` work for you? It can target specific anchors. It will strip of `<script>` though.

Comment: @Twisty no because dom is being created by script on other page

Comment: Then I agree with @charlietfl first statement. Have to emulate a browser to get the JS to be parsed after you collect the source. This could be done in PHP/Curl but I don't see a way to do it in JS.